# Get the non-null data for every field Partitioned by ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this

```
  id  city      province    status    date
----  --------  ----------  --------  ----------
   1  Cainta    Rizal       failed    22/07/2020
   1  nan       nan         success   22/07/2020
   1  nan       nan         success   22/07/2020
   2  Pasig     Manila      success   22/07/2020
   2  nan       nan         failed    22/07/2020
   2  nan       nan         failed    22/07/2020
   3  Marikina  Manila      failed    22/07/2020
   3  nan       nan         success   22/07/2020
   3  nan       nan         success   22/07/2020
```

What I want is to transform the above DataFrame to this one:

```
id  city      province    status    date
----  --------  ----------  --------  ----------
   1  Cainta    Rizal       success   22/07/2020
   2  Pasig     Manila      success   22/07/2020
   3  Marikina  Manila      success   22/07/2020
```

So the criteria is, for every Id with status = 'success', get the non-null values of city and province. I can do this in SQL using this code and I want to replicate this in pandas:

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CITY) AS CITY,
       MAX(PROVINCE) AS PROVINCE,
       'SUCCESS' AS STATUS,
       MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'SUCCESS' THEN DATE END) AS "DATE",
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID
```

I hope my examples were clear. Thank you so much!

EDIT: I would do this to a million-row DF

Comment: I am not sure that this SQL query will do ```for every Id with status = 'success'```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible all missing values per some `id` is better replace missing values by [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html), then filter by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) column `status` and last get first unique rows per `id` by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
cols = ['city','province']
df[cols] = df.groupby(df['id'])[cols].ffill()
df = df.query('status == "success"').drop_duplicates('id')
print (df)
   id      city province   status        date
1   1    Cainta    Rizal  success  22/07/2020
3   2     Pasig   Manila  success  22/07/2020
7   3  Marikina   Manila  success  22/07/2020
```

Comment: the solution worked fine if it is explicitly stated as "nan", but if it is a whitespace or a space, it fills the whole field with it. The workaround i did is replace the whitespace and blanks with the replace() method. actual code is df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True). Thanks BTW!